# Recommend simple software to create calibration print for table leveling

Tags: 3d-models, software, calibration

I've just bought **Anycubic i3 Mega** printer and trying to level it.
So far I've printed test object and 2 others but looks like there are problems with leveling.

I want to make image of 5 small one layer squares(one in each corner and one in center). Looking for recommendations of **simple** software/tutorials/approaches to do it. I tried zbrush but found that it kind of complicated.

Comment: there is a lot of calibration items on thingverse: https://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=calibration

Comment: related/duplicate https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/2665

Comment: This is really 2 questions.  The answer to "get a good text object" has been posted; the answer to "simple CAD tool to get started" is rather opinion-dependent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2479352):

[image: leveling print object]

Note this is for large beds (300 x 300 mm), so you would have to X, Y scale this in your slicer.

This is a simple part that is very easily generated with [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org) 3D design software (very good modeller if you are familiar with software coding), but could easily been designed in any [other tool](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_modeling_software).

Another leveling and centering print that is created with OpenSCAD is [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2280529), and could be a start for you to create your own design:

[image: leveling and centering print object]

Note that the file with the design is located in the "files" section.

**Edit**:
Some code for OpenSCAD made within 5 minutes (I don't type fast so it could have been faster if I did not use the constants, but if you go OpenSCAD, making parametric designs is almost a must ;) ):

```
// Set constants as you like
width = 30;
depth = 30;
layer_height = 0.2;
first_layer_height = 0.2;
nr_of_layers = 2;
box_size = 180;

// Calculated parameters
height = first_layer_height + (nr_of_layers - 1) * layer_height;

// Draw the test object
translate([-width/2, -depth/2,0]){
  // Draw the center square
  cube(size = [width, depth, height], center = false);
  // Draw the corner squares
  for (x=[-1:2:1]){
    for (y=[-1:2:1]){
      translate([x * (box_size-width)/2, y * (box_size-depth)/2, 0])
        cube(size = [width, depth, height], center = false);
    } 
  } 
}
```

Rendered figure:
[image: rendered image of the 5 square level test print]

Comment: I don't see OpenSCAD fitting in the 'easy to use' category. Not for someone who asks which tool is best and has already struggled with their first attempt.

Comment: @0scar thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @seanhoulihane I totally disagree; what is difficult in writing down you want a cube at a certain position, and then you get a cube? **Every** tool has a learning curve, one tool just fits better for some people than other tools do. I did say that if you are a programmer, or familiar with coding, OpenSCAD is an option, especially for this simple request of the OP, I even pointed to a design with an available OpenSCAD file.

Comment: I do agree with @CarlWitthoft that every answer is opinionated. A link with an overview to more tools is added. It is up to the OP to find a tool he/she is comfortable with.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most accessible modelling tools has to be [tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/). Everything is done in the browser, and it even works (to an extent) on a tablet.

I wouldn't recommend getting too attached to it, since it is fairly limited. As an introduction to modeling in 3D, and some of the spatial concepts that you will need to get used to, it works very well.

Comment: i'm sure even tinklecad can handle a few thick squares...